# Angular2 : Render Html trusted characters &times and &copy

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

I am facing issue when rendering **&times** in Component template.

```
@Component({
    selector:'my-app',
    template:`
    <div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="toDoModel" type="text">
    <button (click)="onClickToDo(toDoModel)">Click me</button>      
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of todoList; let i = index">{{item}}
          <a (click)="remove(i)">&times</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>`
})
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: it render as "&times" text.

Comment: Have you tried `&times;` with the `;`?

Comment: @rinukkusu is right. You just need a semicolon. [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XJHPovcop6gUXMJrP1a).

Comment: @rinukkusu thanks it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to put the `;` character at the end of the sequence.

The following will render successfully:

```html
<a (click)="remove(i)">&times;</a>
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPA4w0uyFY4em39FJbLf?p=preview) for example usage

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in the **DomSanitizationService** in angular 2.0.0 (release) - it has been renamed to **DomSanitizer**.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public someSafeHtml: SafeHtml;

    constructor(
        private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.someSafeHtml = this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('&copy; Example.com');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **DomSanitizationService** to parse `&times` correctly as shown below,

**DEMO** : https://plnkr.co/edit/4X2vINBbXmaJ0eHZ9ZZX?p=preview

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector:'my-app',
    template:`
    <div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="toDoModel" type="text">
    <button (click)="onClickToDo(toDoModel)">Click me</button>      
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of todoList; let i = index">{{item}}
          <a (click)="remove(i)" [innerHTML]="myHTML"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>`
})

export class AppComponent{

 dangerousUrl='<span>&times</span>';

 constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {   
    this.myHTML= sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.dangerousUrl);
 }

}
```

## OR

as @rinukkusu suggested,

```
<a (click)="remove(i)">&times;</a>
```

Comment: can you give any other example where **DomSanitizationService** can be needed?

Comment: To generate  html controls dynamically use ca use it. Eg. Checkbox.

Comment: Don't forget to provide `BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS`, if you're going to use the `DomSanitizationService`. Just providing `DomSanitizationService` won't work.

Comment: Check my plunker  @rinukkusu.

Comment: A plunker might not work anymore in the future - a comment will stay :) ... Also it's really nerve wrecking if you don't know, that you have to provide `BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS` - I only found out in the source code of Angular

Comment: What I mean is I dont think it is required. Its good to have.

Comment: Could not find any example for **DomSanitizationService** with dynamically generated html.

Comment: @micronyks yaah, great. you can update it in answer.